# How to pass GoogleApiClient connections to another activity

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I want to connect to Google Play Games in my MainActivity then pass my `mGoogleClientApi` object to my GameActivity.

How do I go about it?

Plus! Every time I start the MainActivity is reconnects to `GoogleApiClient`.

Anything helps.

Comment: One way would be to use the [Singleton pattern](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20singleton%20pattern)

Comment: I don't think that a singleton is best practice here, since it is intended to disconnect from the api at the stop of an activity.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be, if you need to connect to google play games in the main activity
AND in the GameActivity, that you do exactly that thing. There is no need to hand over
a clientApi instance.

I assume that your main activity is kind of a login and afterwards you start the GameActivity?
Than use the api to connect in the first place, handle the login and start the GameActivity.
There you connect to the api again and handle the game relevant part.

Or you could use fragments and hand over the api client via a public method in your activity which 
implements an interface to return the client.

Comment: OK, I wish I could tell you it worked sooner. I'll have to get back to you in a couple hours once my app is uploaded to the dev console.

If I call the same method `mGoogleApiClient.connect();` when onStart() runs it SHOULD connect to the same Google+ account they used in the previous activity correct? 

That is my only concern.

Comment: Yes it will connect the user with the same g+ account, until the user uses the opportunity to (if you have and you should - implemented it) sign out.

Answer (score 0):

Play Game Services are really made with Fragments in mind. It is almost mandatory to use Fragments instead of Activities, and to have a single Activity in your app (that you can made a subclass of GameActivity...)

Comment: Do you have a source backing this claim?

Comment: It may have changed since I posted this two years ago (I don't know), but at the time I have posted that, if your app was using several activities, a client had to be linked to an Activity, you had to connect the client at each activity, and that often lead to having the "Welcome" popup displayed at each activity. So yes, pretty sure this was not meant to be...